# How to reset user password for an RSA II card?

Tags: login

I've got root access on a SLES 9 with a [Remote Supervisor Adapter II Refresh 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Remote_Supervisor_Adapter) card :)

The password for the user for the RSA card is incorrect.

**My question:** How can I reset the RSA user's password without rebooting the machine?

Comment: This isn't really a UNIX & Linux question; it has to do with firmware settings and not with any specific operating system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/...foobar.../asu/asu set RSAString_Password1 PASSWORDHERE
```

but if it doesn't work try to update libusb, since it communicates via USB..

Answer (score 0):

To reset the password and account ID and all RSA II settings, perform the following:

- Boot the machine into BIOS (F1)
- Select `Advanced Setup`
- Select `RSA II settings`
- Select `<<< RESTORE RSA II DEFAULTS >>>`
- Select `Save Values and Reboot RSA II`

The RSA II will lose all settings and be set back to default settings and login:

- Username:  `USERID`
- Password:  `PASSW0RD`

From [the friendly manual](http://www-947.ibm.com/support/entry/portal/docdisplay?lndocid=MIGR-5073695).